# Failed to start application after deploying to tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logback

I developed an application using spring-boot.After creating the war i have deployed it to tomcat using tomcat manager app but when i try to start it it gives me error

```
 FAIL - Application at context path [/webstore-v2] could not be started
```

I checked catalina.out. it is showing an error like this

```
06:01:51,024 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[trace] - openFile(./logs/trace.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/trace.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/trace.log (No such file or directory)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:204)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addStatus(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:32)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addInfo(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:20)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(LogbackServletContainerInitializer.java:32)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5160)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1391)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:698)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
```

So, i guess this can be the cause because of logback.xml.here is my logback

```xml
     <configuration>
    <property name="defaultPattern"
              value="[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    <property name="defaultPath" value="./logs"/>

    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="trace" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${defaultPath}/trace.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${defaultPath}/trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="http-client" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${defaultPath}/http-client.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${defaultPath}/http-client-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="webstore-v2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${defaultPath}/webstore-v2.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${defaultPath}/webstore-v2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="io.applova.webstore" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="io.applova.webstore" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="webstore-v2"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="http-client" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="http-client"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

logs directory can not be created i guess.What should i do?